# Referrer Spoofing in Django

Tags: django, referrer

I have been searching internet for some good docs/articles on how to implement referrer spoofing using django or django templates. 
The project that we are working right now is a dynamic website, where in we get results from mysql database based on the search done by the user.

I am not getting any idea of how to implement this or know of any packages to do this.

Example:

If the original url in mysql database is http://www.google.com and my website is www.example.com.

The link that I should show is www.example.com/redirect/dfjldfjlsdf which will redirect to google.

Note: I am not posting any code/or what I tried because I am not getting any ideas on how to implement this.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a redirection script. The steps are:

> 1. Setup some url handler.
> 2. Setup a view for this handler.
> 3. Setup a meta refresh html template.

Metarefresh template will blank the referrer before sending the end user to the target url.

If you want to get an idea, follow this question and the accepted answer: [django get complete url in query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190819/django-get-complete-url-in-query-string)