# django get complete url in query string

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to implement a redirection script.
The format of the url would be

```
http://localhost:8000/key/url=http://google.com
```

From the above, I want `http://google.com`

When some user visits the above url, it hits the urlpatters defined in the urls.py

```
url(r'^key/url=(.*)', 'homepage.views.redirectquerystring', name="Redirect"),
```

I am trying to get the url `http://google.com` using the below view

```
def redirectquerystring(request):
    para = request.GET.get('url','')
```

But when I do this, I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError at /key/url=http://google.com
redirectquerystring() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Am I doing some mistake here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is much simpler than you think it is.

You're trying to pass `http://google.com` as a parameter, but you're not giving your view a place to receive that parameter.

You need to define your view as `def redirectqyrystring(request, url):`

You don't need to get the url from the request now, it's already there in the variable `url`

Answer (score 3):

You should "capture" the url param using the urlpatterns regex like this:

```
url(r'^key/url=(?P<url>.*)', 'homepage.views.redirectquerystring', name="Redirect"),
```

this way your view receives a parmeter named `url`, which contains the captured url get param.

Comment: `def redirectquerystring(request, url):`

Comment: django is beautiful, isn't it?